# how to refresh parent winform from child winform?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The parent Window Forms button mouse move event is getting correctly into the status bar label of the child window form ... but the opposite of that is not working means "the child window form button mouse move event is not getting displayed into the parent window form status bar label, please help

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One of the good ways to do it is to use events in your child class:

First, declare the event:

```
public partial class ChildForm: Form
{
        public event EventHandler ButtonClicked;
        public ChildForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
}
```

Then call it in the button onClick method of the child form:

...

```
ButtonClicked?.Invoke();
```

...

if your onclick event is `button_onclick` then it would look like:

```
private void button_onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      ButtonClicked?.Invoke();      

}
```

and add your refresh login to this event when you declare this child form from your parent form:

```
var childForm = new ChildForm();
childForm.ButtonClicked += (e,args)=>{
//put the logic here
}
childForm.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a reference like this:

```
   public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
    YourChildForm ycf = new YourChildForm(this);
    ycf.Show();
    }
```

And in your child form:

```
public partial class YourChildForm : Form
{
   MainForm mf_ref
   public YourChildForm(MainForm mf)
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      mf_ref = mf;
   }
}
```

Now you can access to every pubblic method on your mainform just using

```
mf_ref.SomeMethod();
```